# HTML file not showing correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im pretty new to CSS and I managed to use google to assist me making a html file for a previous employer that enables users access to filepaths, programs etc. It was a 1 stop shop for all our needs. It worked great and looked good too.

Since leaving that employer I was unable to bring the work with me however, I remembered the majority of the code I used so i decided I wanted to make the same thing for my new employer.

The issue is for some reason I just cant get the website to look correct. Ideally I wanted a UL list on the left, 3 on the bottom and a contacts section on the right.

I was hoping someone could take a look at the stylesheet and HTML and tell me where im going wrong.

Please and thank you

```css
@import url("reset.css");

body {
   font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
   font-size: 14px;
   colour: #000000;
   background-color: #e6e6e6
}

p {
   padding: 10px;
}

a {
   outline: 0;
}

#wrapper {
   margin: 20px auto;
   width: 1500px;
}

#headerwrap {
   width: 1500px;
   float: left;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {
   height: 100px;
   background-image: url('..\Images\Header - Work Smarter Black Text.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#contentwrap {
   width: 900px;
   float: left;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

#content {
   background: ;
   margin: 0px;
   height: 800px;
}

#contenttop {
   background: #;
   margin-left: 5px;
   height: 400px;
}

#contenttopteam {
   background: #;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
   height: 395px;
   width: 890px;
}

#contenttopteam h3 {
   display: block;
   color: #fff;
   background: #5c1280;
   text-align: center;
   height: 25px;
   line-height: 25px;
   font-size: 100%;
   font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
   border: 0px solid #38174e;
   border-radius: 25px; !important;
   border-bottom: 0px;
   perspective: 1px;
   overflow: hidden;
}


#contenttopteam ul {
   list-style-type: none;
   height: 325px;
   width: 586px;
   margin: 5px;
   background:#;
   padding-top: 5px;
   float: left;
}

#contenttopteam ul a {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    line-height: 139px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 140%;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 3px 3px;
    background: #5c1280;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #38174e;
    border-right: 5px solid #38174e;
    float: left;
    width: 278px;
    height: 147px;
}

#contenttopteam ul a:hover {
   color: #000000;
}

#contenttopteamemail {
   height:330px;
   width:289px;
   background:#;
   float:right;
   margin:5px 5px 5px 0px;
}

#contenttopemail h4 {
   display: block;
   background: #5c1280;
   color: #000000;
   font-size: 100%;
   font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 5px;
   border-bottom: 0px solid #38174e;
   border-radius: 25px;
}

#contenttopemail .form {
   margin: 5px;
   font-size: 120%;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: #000000;
}

#contentbottom {
   background: #;
   margin-left: 5px;
   height: 400px;
}

.contentbottomlinks {
   background: #;
   margin-right: 5px;
   height: 400px;
   width: 293px;
   float: left;
}

.contentbottomlinks h3 {
   display: block;
   color: #fff;
   background: #5c1280;
   text-align: center;
   height: 25px;
   line-height: 25px;
   font-size: 100%;
   font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
   border: 0px solid #38174e;
   border-radius: 25px; !important;
   border-bottom: 0px;
}

.contentbottomlinks ul {
   list-style-type: none;
   height: 330px;
   width: 283;
   margin: 5px;
   background: #;
   padding-top: 5px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    scrollbar-3dlight-color: #c1c1c1;
    scrollbar-arrow-color: #c1c1c1;
    scrollbar-base-color: #f1f1f1;
    scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #a7a7a7;
    scrollbar-face-color: #c1c1c1;
    scrollbar-highlght-color: #a7a7a7;
    scrollbar-shadow-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.contentbottomlinks ul a {
   text-align: center;
   display: block;
   line-height: 30px;
   text-direction: none;
   font-size: 100%;
   colour: #000000;
   margin: 5px 5px;
   background: #fff;
   border-radius: 25px; !important;
   border-bottom: 2px solid #a7a7a7;
   border-right: 2px solid #a7a7a7;
}

.contentbottomlinks ul a:hover {
   color: #38174e;
}

.contentbottomlinks table {
   width:276px
   height: 325px;
   border-collapse: seperate;
   margin-left: 5px;
   background: #;
   text-align: center;
   border: 0px solid #fff;
   border-radius: 25px; !important;
}

.contentbottomlinks td, .contentbottomlinks th 
{
   border: 0px solid #transperant;
   padding: 3px 10px 2px 10px;
   width: 143px;
}

.contentbottom links th 
{
   height: 20px;
   background-colour: #fff;
   color: #000000;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 140%;
}

.contentbottomlinks td 
{
   height: 20px;
   background-color: #fff;
   color: #000000;
   line-hieght: 20px;
}

#leftcolumnwrap {
   width: 300px;
   float: left;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

#leftcolumn {
   background: ;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   height: 800px;
   position: relative;
}

#leftcolumn h3 {
   display: block;
   color: #fff;
   background: #5c1280;
   text-align: center;
   height: 25px;
   line-height: 25px;
   font-size: 100%;
   font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
   border: 0px solid #38174e;
   border-radius: 25px; !important;
   border-bottom: 0px;
}

.leftcolumn ul {
   list-style-type: none;
   height: 730px;
   width: 290px;
   margin: 5px;
   background: #;
   padding-top: 5px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    scrollbar-3dlight-color: #c1c1c1;
    scrollbar-arrow-color: #c1c1c1;
    scrollbar-base-color: #f1f1f1;
    scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #a7a7a7;
    scrollbar-face-color: #c1c1c1;
    scrollbar-highlght-color: #a7a7a7;
    scrollbar-shadow-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#leftcolumn ul a {
   text-align: center;
   display: block;
   line-height: 30px;
   text-direction: none;
   font-size: 100%;
   colour: #000000;
   margin: 5px 5px;
   background: #fff;
   border-radius: 25px; !important;
   border-bottom: 2px solid #a7a7a7;
   border-right: 2px solid #a7a7a7;
}

#leftcolumn ul a:hover {
   color: #000000;
}

#leftcolumn ul li {
position: relative;
}

#leftcolumn span{
   float: right;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0px;
   right: 0px;
   margin-right: 10px;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
   color: #fff;
}

#rightcolumnwrap {
   width: 300px;
   float: right:
   margin 0px;
}

#rightcolumn {
   background: #;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   height: 790px;
   position: relative;
   width: 100%
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    scrollbar-3dlight-color: #c1c1c1;
    scrollbar-arrow-color: #c1c1c1;
    scrollbar-base-color: #f1f1f1;
    scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #a7a7a7;
    scrollbar-face-color: #c1c1c1;
    scrollbar-highlght-color: #a7a7a7;
    scrollbar-shadow-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#rightcolumn h3 {
   display: block;
   color: #fff;
   background: #5c1280;
   text-align: center;
   height: 25px;
   line-height: 25px;
   font-size: 100%;
   font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
   border: 0px solid #38174e;
   border-radius: 25px; !important;
   border-bottom: 0px;
}

#rightcolumn table {
   height: 720px;
   width: 290px;
   margin: 5px;
   background: #;
   padding-top: 5px;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 100%;
   border-radius: 25px;
}

#rightcolumn table img {
   height: 75px;
   float: left;
   margin: 5px;
   border: 0px solid #fff;
}

#rightcolumn span {
   display: block;
   height: 75px;
   width: 70%;
   background: #fff;
   border-radius: 25px; !important;
   border-bottom: 2px solid #38174e;
   border-right: 2px solid #38174e;
   float: left;
   margin: 5px auto;
}

#footerwrap {
   width: 1500px;
   float: left;
   margin: 0 auto;
   clear: both;
}

footer {
   height: 50px;
   background: #;
   margin-top: 5px;
}

#footer marquee {
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 140%;
   line-height: 25px;
}

#dropcontentsubject {
   width: 1495px;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 105%
   color: #fff;
   text-decoration:underline;
   background: #;
   padding-left: 5px;
   padding-top: 5px;
}

.dropcontent {
    width: 1495px;
    height: 30px;
    backgrounf-color: #;
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 100%;
}

/* outercontainer */
.tcontainer {
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden:
   /* hide scroll bar */
}

/* middle containter */.ticker-wrap {
   width: 100%
   padding-left: 100%;
/* push contents to right side of screen */
   background-color: #5c1280;
   font-size: 125%;
   color: #fff;
   border-radius: 25px;
   height: 15px;
}

/* inner container */@keyframes ticker {
 0% {
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
 100% {
   transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}

.ticker.move {
    /* Basically move items from fright side of the screen to left in infinite loop */ 
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding-right: 100%;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-name: ticker;
    animation-duration: 240s;
}

.ticker-move:hover {
   animation-play-state: paused;
   /*pause scroll on mouse hover*/
}

/* items */.ticker-item {
   display: inline-block;
/*lay items in a horizontal line*/  padding: 0 2rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Marine Team Home Screen</title>

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content= "IE=11" />

<!--[if IE]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="script/ticker.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.js"></script>

</head>
      <!-- Add the style sheet. -->
    <link id="theme" rel="stylesheet"
         type="text/css" href="Style/Marine1.css" />
         <script>
           function toggleTheme() {
           // obtains an array of all <link>
           // elements.
           // Select element using indexing.
           var theme = document.getElementsByTagName('link')[0];
           // Change the value of href attribute
          // to change the css sheet.
          if (theme.getAttribute('href') == 'Style/Marine1.css') {
              theme.setAttribute('href', 'Style/marine2.css');
          } else {
              theme.setAttribute('href', 'Style/Marine1.css');
              }
          }
   </script>
</head>

<script>
function myfunction()
{
document.forms["myform"].submit(); //first submit
document.forms['myform']['comments/questions'].Value = 'This feature is currently in development';
}
</script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="headerwrap">
<div id="header">
<FORM method=GET target=_blank action="http://www.google.com/search" style=float;right;margin:5px;">
<input type=hidden name=ie value=utf-8>
<input type=hidden name=oe value=utf-8>
<TABLE bgcolor="transparent"><tr><td>
<A HREF="http://google.com/search?safe=vss" target=_blank>
</A>
<INPUT TYPE=text name=q size=25 maxlength=255 value="" class="input">
<INPUT type=hidden name=safe value=script>
<INPUT type=submit name=sa value="Google Search" style="background: #5c1280;color:#fff;font-weight:bold; >
</td></tr></TABLE>
</FORM>
<input type="button" value="Change Theme" style="width: 115px;float:left;background-color: #5C1280;color:#fff;font-weight:bold;" onclick="toggleTheme()">
</body>
</div>
</div>


<div id="leftcolumnwrap">
<div id="leftcolumn">
<H3>useful links</H3>
<ul>
<!--
####################################################################################################################

                USEFUL LINKS STARTS HERE

####################################################################################################################
-->

<li><a href="https://www.bbc.co.uk/news" target_blank>BBC News</a></li>

<!--
####################################################################################################################

                USEFUL LINKS ENDS HERE

####################################################################################################################
-->

<ul>
</div>
</div>
<div id="contentwrap">
<div id="content">
<div id="contenttop">
<div id="contenttopteam">
<h3>Communication</h3>
<ul>

<!--
####################################################################################################################

                COMMUNICATION STARTS HERE

####################################################################################################################
-->

<li><a href="mailto:email@email.com?Subject=test" target_blank>Email test</a></li>

<!--
####################################################################################################################

                COMMUNICATION ENDS HERE

####################################################################################################################
-->

</ul>
<div id="contenttopteamemail">
<H4>Send Your Feedback Here</h4>
<Form class="form" action="mailto:email.email.com?Subject=Home Screen Feedback" method="post" enctype="text/plain" name="myform" id="myform">
Your Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="Name"
value="" size="20" style="width: 98%;" onkeypress="return handleEnter(this, event)">
<br><br>
Enter your message here:<br>
<textarea rows="10" cols=="32" name="Comments/Questions" value="">
</textarea>
</br></BR>
<input type="button" value="Submit" style="width: 80px;float:right;background-color: #5c1280;color:#fff;font-weight:bold;" onclick="myfunction()">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="contentbottom">
<div class="contentbottomlinks">
<h3>useful tools</h3>
<ul>

<!--
####################################################################################################################

                USEFUL TOOLS STARTS HERE

####################################################################################################################
-->

<li><a href="https://duckduckgo.com/?va=b&t=hc" target_blank>Duck Duck Go</a></li>

<!--
####################################################################################################################

                USEFUL TOOLS ENDS HERE

####################################################################################################################
-->

</ul>
</div>
<div class=contentbottomlinks" style="margin-right:0px">
<h3>Application shortcuts</h3>
<ul>

<!--
####################################################################################################################

                APP SHORTCUTS STARTS HERE

####################################################################################################################
-->

<li><a href="C:\Program Files" target_blank>Program Files</a></li>

<!--
####################################################################################################################

                APP SHORTCUTS ENDS HERE

####################################################################################################################
-->

</ul>
<div>
<div class="contentbottomlinks">
<H3>Useful Websites</H3>
<ul>

<!--
####################################################################################################################

                USEFUL WEBSITES STARTS HERE

####################################################################################################################
-->

<li><a href="https:google.com/" target_blank>Google</a></li>

<!--
####################################################################################################################

                USEFUL WEBSITES ENDS HERE

####################################################################################################################
-->

</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="rightcolumnwrap">
<div id="rightcolumn">
<h3>Contacts</h3>
<table>

<!--
####################################################################################################################

                CONTACTS STARTS HERE

####################################################################################################################
-->

<tr>
<td><img src="**INSERT IMAGE PATH HERE**"><span><p>12345</p></span>

<!--
####################################################################################################################

                CONTACTS ENDS HERE

####################################################################################################################
-->

</table>
</div>
</div>
<div id="footerwrap">
<div id="footer">
<div id="dropcontentsubject"></div>

</div>
</div>
</div>

</script>

<div class="tcontainer"><div class="ticker-wrap"><div class="ticker-move">

<!--
####################################################################################################################

                TICKER STARTS HERE

####################################################################################################################
-->

<div class="ticker-item">Why wont this damn thing work</div>

<!--
####################################################################################################################

                CONTACTS ENDS HERE

####################################################################################################################
-->

</div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can see you are trying to make the layout with `float`. I find floats to be quite tricky, so in general I would suggest looking into the flexbox approach. It allows for a lot of flexibility with layouts. 
[This](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is a great tutorial on how flexbox works.

Comment: Thanks Lily. I will look into this :)

Answer (score 0):

you have some tags unclosed
the nesting of html elements is not correct
and the double quotes some of them are missing

here you are the correct html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Marine Team Home Screen</title>
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content= "IE=11" />
      <!--[if IE]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="script/ticker.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.js"></script>
      <!-- Add the style sheet. -->
      <link id="theme" rel="stylesheet"
         type="text/css" href="Style/Marine1.css" />
      <script>
         function toggleTheme() {
         // obtains an array of all <link>
         // elements.
         // Select element using indexing.
         var theme = document.getElementsByTagName('link')[0];
         // Change the value of href attribute
         // to change the css sheet.
         if (theme.getAttribute('href') == 'Style/Marine1.css') {
            theme.setAttribute('href', 'Style/marine2.css');
         } else {
            theme.setAttribute('href', 'Style/Marine1.css');
            }
         }
      </script>
      <script>
         function myfunction()
         {
         document.forms["myform"].submit(); //first submit
         document.forms['myform']['comments/questions'].Value = 'This feature is currently in development';
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="wrapper">
         <div id="headerwrap">
            <div id="header">
               <form method=GET target=_blank action="http://www.google.com/search" style="float:right;margin:5px;">
                  <input type=hidden name=ie value=utf-8>
                  <input type=hidden name=oe value=utf-8>
                  <table bgcolor="transparent">
                     <tr>
                        <td>
                           <a hrerf="http://google.com/search?safe=vss" target="_blank">
                           </a>
                           <input TYPE=text name=q size=25 maxlength=255 value="" class="input">
                           <input type=hidden name=safe value=script>
                           <input type=submit name=sa value="Google Search" style="background: #5c1280;color:#fff;font-weight:bold;" >
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </table>
               </form>
               <input type="button" value="Change Theme" style="width: 115px;float:left;background-color: #5C1280;color:#fff;font-weight:bold;" onclick="toggleTheme()">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="leftcolumnwrap">
         <div id="leftcolumn">
            <h3>useful links</h3>
            <ul>
               <!--
                  ####################################################################################################################
                  
                                  USEFUL LINKS STARTS HERE
                  
                  ####################################################################################################################
                  -->
               <li><a href="https://www.bbc.co.uk/news" target_blank>BBC News</a></li>
               <!--
                  ####################################################################################################################
                  
                                  USEFUL LINKS ENDS HERE
                  
                  ####################################################################################################################
                  -->
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="contentwrap">
         <div id="content">
            <div id="contenttop">
               <div id="contenttopteam">
                  <h3>Communication</h3>
                  <ul>
                     <!--
                        ####################################################################################################################
                        
                                        COMMUNICATION STARTS HERE
                        
                        ####################################################################################################################
                        -->
                     <li><a href="mailto:email@email.com?Subject=test" target_blank>Email test</a></li>
                     <!--
                        ####################################################################################################################
                        
                                        COMMUNICATION ENDS HERE
                        
                        ####################################################################################################################
                        -->
                  </ul>
                  <div id="contenttopteamemail">
                     <h4>Send Your Feedback Here</h4>
                     <form class="form" action="mailto:email.email.com?Subject=Home Screen Feedback" method="post" enctype="text/plain" name="myform" id="myform">
                     Your Name:<br>
                     <input type="text" name="Name"
                        value="" size="20" style="width: 98%;" onkeypress="return handleEnter(this, event)">
                     <br><br>
                     Enter your message here:<br>
                     <textarea rows="10" cols=="32" name="Comments/Questions" value=""></textarea>
                     </br></BR>
                     <input type="button" value="Submit" style="width: 80px;float:right;background-color: #5c1280;color:#fff;font-weight:bold;" onclick="myfunction()">
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div id="contentbottom">
               <div class="contentbottomlinks">
                  <h3>useful tools</h3>
                  <ul>
                     <!--
                        ####################################################################################################################
                        
                                        USEFUL TOOLS STARTS HERE
                        
                        ####################################################################################################################
                        -->
                     <li><a href="https://duckduckgo.com/?va=b&t=hc" target_blank>Duck Duck Go</a></li>
                     <!--
                        ####################################################################################################################
                        
                                        USEFUL TOOLS ENDS HERE
                        
                        ####################################################################################################################
                        -->
                  </ul>
               </div>
               <div class=contentbottomlinks" style="margin-right:0px">
                  <h3>Application shortcuts</h3>
                  <ul>
                     <!--
                        ####################################################################################################################
                        
                                        APP SHORTCUTS STARTS HERE
                        
                        ####################################################################################################################
                        -->
                     <li><a href="C:\Program Files" target_blank>Program Files</a></li>
                     <!--
                        ####################################################################################################################
                        
                                        APP SHORTCUTS ENDS HERE
                        
                        ####################################################################################################################
                        -->
                  </ul>
                  <div>
                     <div class="contentbottomlinks">
                        <h3>Useful Websites</h3>
                        <ul>
                           <!--
                              ####################################################################################################################
                              
                                              USEFUL WEBSITES STARTS HERE
                              
                              ####################################################################################################################
                              -->
                           <li><a href="https:google.com/" target_blank>Google</a></li>
                           <!--
                              ####################################################################################################################
                              
                                              USEFUL WEBSITES ENDS HERE
                              
                              ####################################################################################################################
                              -->
                        </ul>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div id="rightcolumnwrap">
               <div id="rightcolumn">
                  <h3>Contacts</h3>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <img src="**INSERT IMAGE PATH HERE**">
                        <span>
                           <p>12345</p>
                        </span>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <!--
                     ####################################################################################################################
                     
                                     CONTACTS ENDS HERE
                     
                     ####################################################################################################################
                     -->
                  </table>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div id="footerwrap">
               <div id="footer">
                  <div id="dropcontentsubject"></div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="tcontainer">
            <div class="ticker-wrap">
               <div class="ticker-move">
                  <!--
                     ####################################################################################################################
                     
                                     TICKER STARTS HERE
                     
                     ####################################################################################################################
                     -->
                  <div class="ticker-item">Why wont this damn thing work</div>
                  <!--
                     ####################################################################################################################
                     
                                     CONTACTS ENDS HERE
                     
                     ####################################################################################################################
                     -->
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you Nariman. Looks like I got sloppy :) looks like you fixed my header issue however, im still having issues with the layout.

Thanks again